# Node.js API response body is empty

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using an express api endpoint for user registration. Everything on the server side is working fine, however when I print the api response on the client side, I'm not seeing the body that I'm passing in the response.

Here is my api code:

```
app.post('/register', function(req, res) {
    async function f1() {
      console.log(req.body);
      var newUser = [req.body.name, req.body.password];
      var sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, password) VALUES (?, ?)";
      await MySQLConnection.query(sql, newUser, function(err, result){
          console.log("starting first query");
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log("User Added");
      });

      var sql = "SELECT * from users where password=?";
      await MySQLConnection.query(sql, req.body.password, function(err, user){
        console.log("Starting second query");
        if (err) throw err;
        const payload = {
          "id": user[0].ID,
          "name": user[0].name,
          "admin": user[0].admin
        }
        var token = jwt.sign(payload, app.get('superSecret'), {
          expiresIn: 60*60*2
        });
        console.log(token);
        var response = ({
          success: true,
          message: 'Successfully registered',
          token: token
        });
        console.log(response);
        return response;
      });
      return req.body.name;
    }
    f1();
    return res.status(200).send({"message": 'testing response'});
 });
```

And then here is my code on the client side that is making the request:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8000/register',
  {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({name: this.state.name, password: passwordHash.generate(this.state.password)})
  }).then((response, err) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log(response);
  });
```

And then here is what I'm seeing in the client console:

```
Response { type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:8000/register", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, bodyUsed: false }
```

So I would expect to see the message somewhere in the response, but I can't figure out why it isn't appearing anywhere. What is interesting is that in the server code, I can set res.status(500) and the client will acknowledge that it received a 500 response.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: `.then((response, err)` ... fetch uses promises, promises .then only ever get a single parameter, so, not sure what you think you'll get in err (always undefined)

Comment: as for `bodyUsed` being `false` - at that stage, it has not yet been used, therefore that is perfectly correct - perhaps you need to read [how to use fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: now that you changed the title ... body is empty? no, there is no body property, you haven't even tried to access the body of the response yet ... hint, `return response.json()` if the body is json ... which it seems to be .. and in a new `.then(body => console.log(body))` you'll see the body

Comment: That was exactly it. I thought I had tried using `response.json().then`  before, but evidently I missed something when I was using it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Off topic, you might want to hash your password on the server side.